# Regular Expression RegEx to validate Custom Excel formats

Tags: c#, regex, excel

I am creating Excel spreadsheets programmaticly (in C#/.Net using [the fabulous EPPlus library](http://epplus.codeplex.com)) and am passing in an array of cell ranges (string-based) and the custom format string to apply to these ranges.

```
// Struct:
public struct ExcelColumnFormat
{
    public string CellRangeDefinition;
    public string ExcelFormatString;
}
```

-

```
// Usage
ExcelHelper.ExcelColumnFormat[] formats = new ExcelHelper.ExcelColumnFormat[1];
formats[0].ExcelFormatString = "$#,##0.00";
formats[0].CellRangeDefinition = "I:I";
```

-

```
// Consumption / application of those formats
foreach (ExcelColumnFormat format in formats)
{
    // Make sure that there are non-zero or null strings passed in
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(format.ExcelFormatString) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(format.CellRangeDefinition))
        ws.Cells[format.CellRangeDefinition].Style.Numberformat.Format = format.ExcelFormatString;
}
```

I am already checking the strings for IsNullOrEmpty, but I wanted to put another level of validation to test if the custom format strings are, in fact, valid Excel formats.  Here is a [link to the Office help file that describes the rules around Excel Formats](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview14.aspx?AssetId=HP010342372&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL&Version=14&tl=2&CTT=5&origin=HA010352461).

**The question is:** given the many permutations available in custom Excel formats, is this a worthwhile endeavor and how might the RegEx look?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm sure you could write a regex to validate the format string, but it would be quite tedious to author. And you risk that any omission or mistake on your part will potentially reject a valid format string.  I am not sure the right words to describe it, but this is a situation where the algorithmic complexity is low, but the rule complexity is high.

Comment: I ended up trying VBA but didn't want to use Interop/OLE/Excel API calls, and ultimately ended up restricting the input for the filters instead of trying to validate every possible permutation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could let VBA figure it out:

```
On Error GoTo complain
junk = Format(dummyData,formatString)
...
```

The dummyData could be a reference to a cell in the given range if the type of data isn't known.